# Linux: How to programmatically ensure a file is not cached in RAM?

Tags: linux, file, caching, filesystems

I have an unusual requirement in that I need to ensure that a large that file that I just created is not cached in RAM at all, because it is a file that I plan to read at a much later date. Is there a way to flag a file so that it is not cached in RAM while I'm writing it? The OS is Linux.

Comment: [fadvise](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fadvise) with `FADV_DONTNEED` looks vaguely relevant. Is there some reason why you care about this caching thing? The OS usually can figure these things out fine by itself.

Comment: Ah thanks. Yes I have more important data in RAM and I don't want it flushed. I don't trust the kernel to do the right thing. It was written by mere people after all.

Comment: So, `mlock` that data as well/instead?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/290362/454215